# glReadPixels white spots issues

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glreadpixels

I'm trying to make a screenshot on my iPad with OpenGL ES. This does work, but there are blank spots on them. These blank spots seem to be the rendered object. I've tried using the other buffers aswell, but none of them seem to contain the actual 3D object?

I'm using the example code of String SDK.

Image of the issue:

[image: The issue]

*EAGLView.m*

```
- (void)createFramebuffer
{
    if (context && !defaultFramebuffer)
    {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

        // Handle scale
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentScaleFactor:)])
        {
            float screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

            self.contentScaleFactor = screenScale;
        }

        // Create default framebuffer object.
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);

        // Create color render buffer and allocate backing store.
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
        [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &framebufferWidth);
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &framebufferHeight);

        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

        // Create and attach depth buffer
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight);

        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

        // Bind color buffer
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

        if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
            NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    }
}
```

*Screenshot code*

*EAGLView.m*

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot:(UIView*)eaglview
{
    GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;

    // Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
    // If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point,
    // this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
    // Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.
    //glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, _colorRenderbuffer);

    // Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    // If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
    // otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                    ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
    // Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
    NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
        // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
        // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
        // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
        CGFloat scale = eaglview.contentScaleFactor;
        widthInPoints = width / scale;
        heightInPoints = height / scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
    }
    else {
        // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
        widthInPoints = width;
        heightInPoints = height;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
    }

    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
    // Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
    // The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Clean up
    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    return image;
}
```

*String_OGL_TutorialViewController.m*

```
- (void)render
{
    [(EAGLView *)self.view setFramebuffer];

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    const int maxMarkerCount = 10;
    struct MarkerInfoMatrixBased markerInfo[10];

    int markerCount = [stringOGL getMarkerInfoMatrixBased: markerInfo maxMarkerCount: maxMarkerCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < markerCount; i++)
    {
        float diffuse[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
        diffuse[markerInfo[i].imageID % 3] = 1;

        if ([context API] == kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2)
        {
            glUseProgram(program);
            glUniform4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR], 1, diffuse);

            const float translationMatrix[16] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -cubeScale, 1};
            float modelViewMatrix[16];
            float modelViewProjectionMatrix[16];

            [String_OGL_TutorialViewController multiplyMatrix: translationMatrix withMatrix: markerInfo[i].transform into: modelViewMatrix];
            [String_OGL_TutorialViewController multiplyMatrix: modelViewMatrix withMatrix: projectionMatrix into: modelViewProjectionMatrix];

            glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MVP], 1, GL_FALSE, modelViewProjectionMatrix);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ((float *)NULL) + 6 * 4 * 3);

            // Validate program before drawing. This is a good check, but only really necessary in a debug build.
            // DEBUG macro must be defined in your debug configurations if that's not already the case.
#if defined(DEBUG)
            if (![self validateProgram:program])
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to validate program: %d", program);
                return;
            }
#endif
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
            glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
            glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);

            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 12, NULL);
            glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 12, ((float *)NULL) + 6 * 4 * 3);

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadMatrixf(projectionMatrix);

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

            glLoadIdentity();
            glMultMatrixf(markerInfo[i].transform);
            glTranslatef(0, 0, -cubeScale);

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
        }
        UIImage *img = [(EAGLView *)self.view snapshot: self.view];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        [stringOGL pause];

    }
}
```